# Correct use of save button code

Tags: java, android

So I've been learning and trying to build upon an app I made by following an online tutorial. It is a simple, bare bones, note taking application. The mainActivity simply shows note objects in a list view. The second screen/activity is the one I'm currently working on, trying to add code where I can. So far I've added a save button that will simply save the text/string value and take the user back to the main activity. I would like some feedback as to my implementation of the onButtonSave method:

```
public class NoteEditorActivity extends Activity {

private NoteItem note;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    note = new NoteItem();
    note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
    note.setText(intent.getStringExtra("text"));

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    et.setText(note.getText());
    et.setSelection(note.getText().length());
    // I'm wondering if this is the correct way to call my onButtonSave method
    onButtonSave();
}

private void saveAndFinish() {
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    String noteText = et.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
    intent.putExtra("text", noteText);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        saveAndFinish();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    saveAndFinish();
}

// This is the code I've added for the save button.
public void onButtonSave(){
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setText("Saved!");
        saveAndFinish(); }
    });
   }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Feedback about what exactly? Is it not working?

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. It is working. I just want to know if it is correct in the way I wrote the method and called it in the onCreate(). Feedback on my logic as far how I implement new elements to the application, I want to know if I am on the right path. @codeMagic

Comment: You called that function `onButtonSave()`. That is no good as it looks like a handler that you should not call yourself. Better rename it to something like installSaveButton. But then i wonder why you need a separate function for that. Better do all in onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are curious as to whether or not you have covered all your cases.  Breaking up the setup of listeners and UI components from your `onCreate` into separate methods can be a good practice for easier readability when there are a lot of things being initialized.

You cover the case when the back button is used.

You cover the case when the user presses the button.

From what can be seen you also cover the case with the menu selection of leaving the screen.  A couple people have talked best about how to detect whether the screen goes to the background or not.  If you really want to catch all cases, you can do your save within the `onPause()` of an Activity.  This will be fired if you press back, go home or call another activity.

Distinguishing between another activity and the home button is tough.  But some people have pointed towards `onUserHint()` as a way to detect this.  Just thought I would provide some feedback to what I can understand of your question.